# Element 'css', attribute 'order': The attribute 'order' is not allowed

Tags: magento2.2

After Update magento 2.2.0 i am getting below error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'css', attribute 'order': The attribute 'order' is not allowed.
Line: 52

Element 'css', attribute 'order': The attribute 'order' is not allowed.
Line: 53

Element 'css', attribute 'order': The attribute 'order' is not allowed.
Line: 54


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'css', attribute 'order': The attribute 'order' is not allowed.
Line: 52

Element 'css', attribute 'order': The attribute 'order' is not allowed.
Line: 53

Element 'css', attribute 'order': The attribute 'order' is not allowed.
Line: 54

#0 /vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('__construct('createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '\n   load(Array)
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 /vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#15 /vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'home')
#16 /generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
#17 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#31 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 /index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#34 {main}
```

Comment: There is an issue on this : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12188.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove order in css like

```
<css src="Vendor_MOdule::css/owl.transitions.css" media="all" order="999"/>
```

replace

```
<css src="Vendor_MOdule::css/owl.transitions.css" media="all" />
```

Hope it work for you

Comment: do you have any idea if i want to change order of css then how can we do that?

Comment: @NavinBhudiya Currently i am working on this issue when i got solution i will share ASAP

Comment: @SagarDobariya have you found the alternative for order attribute?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on this topic ( https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12188 ). I included a patch in a comment. In the same time, I opened a pull request ( https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12235 ) to fix this issue.

The patch :
Here is a patch that can be installed with the help cweagans/composer-patches library. Create a file Patch-Magento_Framework-M2.2.0-the-attribute-order-is-not-allowed.patch in the patches folder in the Magento root directory with the following content.

```
--- View/Layout/etc/head.xsd
+++ View/Layout/etc/head.xsd
@@ -19,6 +19,7 @@
         <xs:attribute name="target" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:attribute name="src_type" type="xs:string"/>
+        <xs:attribute name="order" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:complexType>

     <xs:complexType name="metaType">
```

In composer.json append :

```
"extra": {
    "patches": {
        "magento/framework": {
            "Fix: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12188": "patches/Patch-Magento_Framework-M2.2.0-the-attribute-order-is-not-allowed.patch"
        }
    },
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

Run a composer update.